Question about normal extension K/F and subgroups of Galois group (Chapter 5 of Herstein)
I am having some trouble with Theorem 5.T (or 5.6.4 in the second ed.) of Herstein's Topics in Algebra, which is concerned with the normal field extensions and the associated groups of automorphisms.
Background:
Given fields $F \subseteq K$, let $G := G(K,F)$ be the set of $F$-preserving automorphisms of $K$. We have seen already in Theorem 5.R that $\# G \leq [K:F]$. For a subgroup $H$ of $G$ the fixed field of $H$ is $K_H := \{ x \in K :\sigma(x) = x~ \forall ~\sigma \in H \}$. Clearly $F \subseteq K_G$. We say that a finite field extension is normal if $F = K_G$.

Statement of Theorem 5.T:  Let $K$ be a normal extension of $F$. Then

$[K:K_H] = \# H$.
$H = G(K,K_H)$.

In particular, by setting $H=G$ we see that $[K:F] = \# G$.

Question: Is it true that $1.$ and $2.$ above hold even when $K$ is not a normal extension of $F$? In other words, is the following amended statement correct?

Amended statement of Theorem 5.T:  Let $K$ be a finite extension of $F$. Then

$[K:K_H] = \# H$.
$H = G(K,K_H)$.

In particular, if $K$ is a normal extension of $F$, then $[K:F] = \# G(K,F)$.

It's just I'm having trouble seeing where the assumptions of normality (beyond finiteness of field extension) is used in the proof, apart from the conclusion of the theorem. For completeness, here's the proof of the amended statement, which follows exactly the proof of the original statement.
Proof.
We have the relations $H \leq G(K,K_H) \leq G(K,F)$ of subgroups. Also, we have seen in Theorem 5.R that $[K:K_H] \geq \# G(K,K_H)$, which in turn implies that $[K,K_H] \geq \# H$. It remains to establish that $\# H \geq [K,K_H]$, as this will automatically imply both $[K,K_H] = \# H$ and $G(K,K_H) = H$.
Since $K/F$ is finite, so is $K/K_H$. By Theorem 5.P there exists an element $a$ of $K$ such that $K = K_H(a)$. List $H = \{ \sigma_1, \ldots, \sigma_h \}$, and for $1 \leq k \leq h$ define the polynomial
\begin{align*}
p(x) = \prod_{i=1}^h (x - \sigma_i(a))= \sum_{k =0}^n x^{n-k}(-1)^k \alpha_k,
\end{align*}
where $\alpha_0 = 1$ and $\alpha_k := \sum_{S \subset [h] : \# S= k } \prod_{i \in S} \sigma_i(a)$ for $1 \leq k \leq h$. Note that for $\sigma \in H$, $\sigma \alpha_k = \alpha_k$, so that $\alpha_k$ are in $K_H$. In particular, $p(x)$ is a polynomial with coefficients in $K_H$ for which the element $a$ of $K$ is a root. Thus the degree, $h = \# H$, of this polynomial is at least that degree of the field extension $[K:K_H]$. It follows that $\# H \geq [K:K_H]$, completing the proof.
If $K$ is a normal extension of $F$, then $K_G = F$. Thus setting $G = H$ in the above we obtain $[K:F] = \# G(K,F)$. $\square$.
Is there an error where I should have used the normality of the extension earlier than in the final sentence of the proof?
Thank you in advance for any help, comments, or thoughts!

This is Theorem 5.2 on Page 17 of Keith Conrad's Notes on Galois Theory where it is attributed to Artin.
Theorem 5.2 (Artin). Let $E$ be a field and $H$ be a finite group of automorphisms of $E$. If $[E : E_H ]$ is finite then E/E_H is a Galois extension and $Gal(E/E_H ) = H$.
